# Are there any known problems with the amsref "partial" field?

Tags: amsrefs

I am having trouble with the "partial" field in an amsref bibliography entry, viz., there are three "partial" fields but the output entry contains four journal references.  The LaTeX is

```
    \bib{Rob1938}{article}{
    label = {Rob1938},
    author = {Robinson, G. de B.},
    title = {On the representations of the symmetric group},
    partial = {
        journal = {Amer. J. Math.},
        volume = {60},
        date = {1938},
        pages = {745--760},
        %review = {\MR{***}},
        eprint = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371609},
        doi = {10.2307/2371609},
    },
    partial = {
        journal = {Amer. J. Math.},
        volume = {69},
        date = {1947},
        pages = {286--298},
        %review = {\MR{***}},
        eprint = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371853},
        doi = {10.2307/2371853},
    },
    partial = {
        title = {On the representations of the symmetric group (third paper)},
        journal = {Amer. J. Math.},
        volume = {70},
        date = {1948},
        pages = {277--294},
        %review = {\MR{***}},
        eprint = {https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372326},
        doi = {10.2307/2372326},
    },
}
```

The text of the output entry is

```
[Rob1938] G. de B. Robinson, On the representations of the symmet-
ric group., Amer. J. Math. 60 (1938), 745–760;, Amer. J.
Math. 69 (1947), 286–298;, Amer. J. Math. 70 (1948), 277–
294, Amer. J. Math. 70 (), 277–294, DOI 10.2307/2372326,
available at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372326.
```

Note that the final "Amer. J. Math. 70 (), 277–294" is extraneous (and mostly duplicates the third journal reference).

Comment: Please provide code we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I wrapped your `\bib...` listing inside `\begin{document}\begin{bibdiv}\begin{biblist}... \end{biblist}\end{bibdiv}\end{document}` and with preamble `\documentclass{amsart} \usepackage{amsrefs}` the output prints exactly as expected. (well, not quite, I consider it a bug that `partial` does not have `\PrintDOI`, but I emphatically do not get the output you showed).

Comment: I checked into this and Wong is correct; the underlying problem is some local modifications I made to amsrefs.  Without the mods, it works OK.

Comment: WWong:  Now that you mention it, I see that I have the same DOI problem, and also a problem with partial eprint.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705336/amsrefs-partial-does-not-print-doi-eprint-or-note-fields/705337 for a fix; it's not difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem is some local modifications I made to amsrefs. Without the mods, it works OK.